# Getting data from service to MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to populate MatTableDataSource with data from CustomService.

Here is my component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent  {

  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];

  constructor(private userService: CustomService) {  }
  const USER_DATA: User[] = this.userService.getUser();
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.USER_DATA);

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

}
```

Service code:

```
  @Injectable()
    export class CustomService {
      test: boolean = true;
      private serviceUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl);
      }
    }
```

In VSCode I receive this error on  USER_DATA
Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'User[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Comment: getUser returns an observable. Your USER_DATA is of type User [], which is not an observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to Observable as follows,

```
 this.userService.getUser()
        .subscribe(users => { 
            this.USER_DATA= users; 
}, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

declare USER_DATA above the constructor as ,

```
const USER_DATA: User[] =[];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a direct `observable` to your constant

Instead, you should subscribe to it and then assign as follows

```
const USER_DATA: User[]

constructor() {
   this.userService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
      this.USER_DATA = user;
   });
}
```

NOTE :
And also, this code has to be inside the function scope and not directly inside the class as you are doing it now.